# Why using print() function in google colab saves it from running out of ram?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ram

I have been using google colab for a while and I have been working with very large datasets sometimes finishing off the RAM of google collab, I actually ended up renting collab PRO so now I have 25GB of Ram, and it was working fine, but it happened something wierd which is that I ran out of RAM with this code:

```py
trainX1 = np.zeros((200, 3508, 2480))
trainY1 = np.zeros(200)
P = 0
D = 0
for x in range(200):
  k = random.randint(0, 1)
  if k == 1:
    if P < 100:
      trainX1[x, :, :] = np.load(pathP + '/' + NamesP1_train[P])
      trainY1[x] = 0
      P = P + 1
    else:
      trainX1[x, :, :] = np.load(pathD + '/' + NamesD1_train[D])
      trainY1[x] = 1
      D = D + 1
  else:
    if D < 100:
      trainX1[x, :, :] = np.load(pathD + '/' + NamesD1_train[D])
      trainY1[x] = 1
      D = D + 1
    else:
      trainX1[x, :, :] = np.load(pathP + '/' + NamesP1_train[P])
      trainY1[x] = 0
      P = P + 1
```

So naturally for debuggin I added **print(x)** function to determine how many iterations could I actually handle, but then it finished, so I was really confused, anyone knows why this happens?
the **print(x)** function was added before the
**k = random.randint(0,1) function**

Comment: Hard to say. There is an element of randomness. Are you explicitly setting the random seed to make sure you are doing the exact same thing when you add `print`?

Comment: No I´m not setting the radom seed, but I also tested just writing k = 1 and it worked out just fine, so then it´s because of the random.randint() function?

Comment: I have 9GB of RAM left